# Complex Elastic Search Query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following documents in the elastic search index.

```
[{
        "_index": "ten2",
        "_type": "documents",
        "_id": "c323c2244a4a4c22_en-us",
        "_source": {
            "publish_details": [{
                    "environment": "603fe91adbdcff66",
                    "time": "2020-06-24T13:36:55.514Z",
                    "locale": "hi-in",
                    "user": "aadab2f531206e9d",
                    "version": 1
                },
                {
                    "environment": "603fe91adbdcff66",
                    "time": "2020-06-24T13:36:55.514Z",
                    "locale": "en-us",
                    "user": "aadab2f531206e9d",
                    "version": 1
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2020-06-24T13:36:43.037Z",
            "_in_progress": false,
            "title": "Entry 1",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "url": "/entry-1",
            "tags": [],
            "uid": "c323c2244a4a4c22",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-24T13:36:43.037Z",
            "fields": []
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "ten2",
        "_type": "documents",
        "_id": "c323c2244a4a4c22_mr-in",
        "_source": {
            "publish_details": [{
                "environment": "603fe91adbdcff66",
                "time": "2020-06-24T13:37:26.205Z",
                "locale": "mr-in",
                "user": "aadab2f531206e9d",
                "version": 1
            }],
            "created_at": "2020-06-24T13:36:43.037Z",
            "_in_progress": false,
            "title": "Entry 1 marathi",
            "locale": "mr-in",
            "url": "/entry-1",
            "tags": [],
            "uid": "c323c2244a4a4c22",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-24T13:37:20.092Z",
            "fields": []
        }
    }
]
```

And I want Result [] blank from this. As here we can see that uid of both the documents is the same. I am using the following query to get result :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.environment": "603fe91adbdcff66"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "en-us"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "hi-in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "mr-in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But the above query gives me all 2 documents, but I want results as bank the reason here is here uid is common and that uid contains all three local in publishing details. So is way to get a valid result, Is any aggregation query that helps me here. it is just a sample I have so many documents to filter out. Kindle Helps me here.

Comment: help me into the above query to get valid results.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: @Gibbs I have shared my elastic search documents list and query. I want an empty result but my query giving all documents. so I want such a query that gives me a blank result. the query related to publish_details.locale and publish_details.environment.

Comment: You are saying that same uid and check for all 3 locale!?

Comment: Yes, value of uid field is the same for both documents.

Comment: is any query option available in elastic search to get the result that I want @Gibbs kindly help me into this.

Comment: Sure, Are you allowed to change little bit of mapping?

Comment: What is the mapping for `uid`? Is It keyword? Can you add that also

Comment: mapping of uid field: {"uid":{"type":"text","fields":{"raw":{"type":"keyword"}}}} and publish details: {"publish_details":{"type":"nested","properties":{"action":{"type":"keyword"},"entry_locale":{"type":"keyword"},"environment":{"type":"keyword"},"job_id":{"type":"keyword"},"locale":{"type":"keyword"},"scheduled_at":{"type":"date"},"time":{"type":"date"},"user":{"type":"keyword"},"version":{"type":"integer"}}}}

Comment: If data loss then I can't allow to update the mapping. is this possible to get results with the same mapping?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs sorry to disturb you again but is any query for this to get a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uid.raw"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "publish_details"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "locales": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "publish_details.locale"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will group you by `uid` first then `publish_details.locale`

It provides results as below

```
"aggregations": {
        "agg1": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "c323c2244a4a4c22",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "agg2": {
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "locales": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "en-us",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "hi-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "mr-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "c323c2244rrffa4a4c22",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "agg2": {
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "locales": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "en-us",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "hi-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

I have three docs where two has same id and other one is different.

I will update the query further to remove the first result where you have 3 buckets.  You also can proceed further to handle it in the code.

You can do that. `10k` documents is fine. But when you have in millions, you should have enough resources to execute this.

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query":{
      "bool" :{
          "must_not":{
              "match":{
                "publish_details.environment":"603fe91adbdcff66"
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uid.raw"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "details": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "publish_details"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "locales": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "publish_details.locale"
              }
            },   
            "unique_locales": {
                "value_count": {
                    "field": "publish_details.locale"
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations": {
        "uids": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "c323c2244a4a4c22",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "details": {
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "locales": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "en-us",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "hi-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "mr-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "unique_locales": {
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "c323c2244rrffa4a4c22",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "details": {
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "locales": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "en-us",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "hi-in",
                                    "doc_count": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "unique_locales": {
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks, For the reply. But I have more than 10K documents and need to filter them also can I use here publish_details.environemnt. means need to ignore those documents whose uid is the same and  publish_details.environemnt is: 603fe91adbdcff66 and publish_details.locales is: hi-in,en-us,mr-in.

Comment: are aggregations required here? or is any way to directly get the result like the query that I used there. the reason here is aggregation with query gives result "hits" and aggregation both. I want the whole details of other documents.

Comment: It will not give hits because I set size as 0. And I don't think there is a way without aggregation. Because it is between the documents.

Comment: thanks, it is not giving hits, but what about other fields in documents. means suppose I have 3 documents and I want only one in response with other fields like title, url, etc, how we can get that fields here with aggregation?

Comment: Yes, I am asking so many questions , sorry for that but still not able to get exact query I have created another post for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574006/elastic-search-aggregation-and-complex-query please help me here.