# Elastic Search Aggregation and Complex Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have created the index

```
PUT ten2
{
    "mappings": {
        "documents": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },"uid": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "publish_details": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "environment": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "locale": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "time": {
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "version": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and added documents into it. here is the list of documents:

```
   [{
    "_index": "ten2",
    "_type": "documents",
    "_id": "blt69b62b48bbed1fb6_en-us",
    "_source": {
        "publish_details": [{
                "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
                "time": "2020-06-24T12:11:25.276Z",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
                "version": 1
            },
            {
                "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
                "time": "2020-06-24T12:11:25.276Z",
                "locale": "hi-in",
                "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
                "version": 1
            }
        ],
        "title": "Entry 1",
        "uid": "blt69b62b48bbed1fb6"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "ten2",
    "_type": "documents",
    "_id": "blt69b62b48bbed1fb6_mr-in",
    "_source": {
        "publish_details": [{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "time": "2020-06-24T12:12:35.467Z",
            "locale": "mr-in",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
            "version": 1
        }],
        "title": "Entry 3",
        "uid": "blt69b62b48bbed1fb6"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "ten2",
    "_type": "documents",
    "_id": "blt4044c5198122a3ed_en-us",
    "_source": {
        "publish_details": [{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
            "version": 1
        },{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff6690",
            "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
            "version": 1
        }],
        "title": "Entry 10",
        "uid": "blt4044c5198122a3ed"
    }
}
```

]
and I want the following result

```
    [
 {
    "_index": "ten2",
    "_type": "documents",
    "_id": "blt4044c5198122a3ed_en-us",
    "_source": {
        "publish_details": [{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
            "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
            "version": 1
        },{
            "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff6690",
            "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
            "version": 1
        }],
        "title": "Entry 10",
        "uid": "blt4044c5198122a3ed"
    }
}

]
```

I am using the following query to get the result

```
GET ten2/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                        "publish_details.environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "en-us"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "hi-in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "publish_details",
                                    "query": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publish_details.locale": "mr-in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

kindly help me a query to get expected result. First two dicuemtns having same uid only publish_details.locale is different.I am using must query within must_not to get result, currently I am getting all three documents but I want only last one. I have million documwnts.

Comment: Is it related to your other question? can you explain the logic little more?

Comment: uid of the first two documents are the same that means uid: blt69b62b48bbed1fb6 is published on all 3 locales. so I don't want that document in the result.

Answer (score 0):

To know more about Bool queries refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

**Adding a working example with your mapping, index data, and with the search query**

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "publish_details",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "publish_details.locale": "en-us"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "publish_details.environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "publish_details.locale": "hi-in"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "publish_details.locale": "mr-in"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.53899646,
            "_source": {
                "publish_details": [
                    {
                        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff66",
                        "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
                        "locale": "en-us",
                        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
                        "version": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff6690",
                        "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
                        "locale": "en-us",
                        "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
                        "version": 1
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Entry 10",
                "uid": "blt4044c5198122a3ed"
            },
            "inner_hits": {
                "publish_details": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": {
                            "value": 1,
                            "relation": "eq"
                        },
                        "max_score": 0.53899646,
                        "hits": [
                            {
                                "_index": "test",
                                "_type": "_doc",
                                "_id": "3",
                                "_nested": {
                                    "field": "publish_details",
                                    "offset": 1
                                },
                                "_score": 0.53899646,
                                "_source": {
                                    "environment": "blt603fe91adbdcff6690",
                                    "time": "2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z",
                                    "locale": "en-us",
                                    "user": "bltaadab2f531206e9d",
                                    "version": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

To know more about inner hits refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html)

**The above query returns only the third document, thus satisfying the conditions of the search query. In the Inner Hits, only one part of the third document is returning, and the part which is matching `blt603fe91adbdcff66` is discarded.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my question is different here. First, two documents having the same uid(blt69b62b48bbed1fb6) only publish_details.locale is different so I want the query along with uid to get the result and it is just sample I have millions of documents. So kindly help me into this?

Comment: @Suraj Dalvi can you please explain what you mean by **I want the query along with uid to get the result **, what is the criteria on which you want your result ?

Comment: as I told you that uid of the first two documents are the same that means uid: blt69b62b48bbed1fb6 is published on all 3 locales. so I don't want that document in the result.

Comment: need a generic query for that @Bhavya

Comment: Okay, @Suraj Dalvi I now understood what u were trying to say :)

Comment: Kindly help into the query @Bhavya

Comment: is any way to get the expected result?

Comment: @Suraj Dalvi I have updated my question, please go through the search query and search result, and let me know if this was what you required. ( I have used Inner Hits in the search query)

Comment: @SurajDalvi did you get a chance to go through my updated answer? Please have a look at the search result, is this what you require?  Looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Thanks For the reply @Bhavya but the above query not working for me it is giving me the blank result.

Comment: Suppose I have following documents also : [{"_index":"ten2","_type":"documents","_id":"blt4044c5198122a3ed_en-us","_source":{"publish_details":[{"environment":"blt603fe91adbdcff66","time":"2020-06-24T12:10:46.430Z","locale":"en-us","user":"bltaadab2f531206e9d","version":1}],"title":"Entry 11","uid":"blt4044c5198122a3ee"}},{"_index":"ten2","_type":"documents","_id":"blt4044c5198122a3ed_en-us","_source":{"publish_details":[],"title":"Entry 12","uid":"blt4044c5198122a3ef"}}] then how I ca get result that include Entry10,Entry 11, Entrry 12. in this case above query doesn't work.

Comment: needs a query that focuses on uid if uid is the same then combine it's publish_details and then query on them for the result.publish_details may be blank for some documents so can't able to rely on {"match":{"publish_details.locale":"en-us"}}(locale).Kindly help me here. @Bhavya

Comment: Okay @SurajDalvi I will try, and let u know

Comment: something like mongo aggregation query: [{ $match: {_publish_locale: { $in: params.unpublished_locales },
 _publish_environment:params.unpublished_environment}},{$group:{_id: "$uid",COUNTER: { $sum: 1 }}},
{$match: {COUNTER: { $eq: params.unpublished_locales.length }}}]. It is not actual query but need query like this.

Comment: hi, @Bhavya did you find any solution for this?

Comment: any aggregation query to get a result?

Comment: Sorry @SurajDalvi, but I am not able to create any sort of generic query that you want :/

Comment: okay @Bhavya but do you feel any option to achieve the result. means any steps for that to get a result?